# Arch cryptsetup hangs on 'waiting for zero'

Tags: arch-linux, udev, udevd

Cryptsetup was working flawlessly for months, but something I did today on my system now makes it hang:

```
# cryptsetup --debug --verbose luksOpen /dev/sdb home --key-file=/home.key --verbose
...
Key slot 1 unlocked.
...
# Udev cookie 0xd4d949a (semid 32768) decremented to 1
# Udev cookie 0xd4d949a (semid 32768) waiting for zero
```

Also when I do `lsblk -f`, I used to get UUIDs for all of the devices (including `sdb`) but now I only get a UUID and FSTYPE for the rootfs (every other device is listed, but FSTYPE, LABEL, and UUID are empty). `blkid` however does show the a UUID for all devices.

I also do not see any network devices - `eth0` and `wlp4s0` are missing from `ip link` and `ifconfig`.

When I boot from the original live USB, everything works perfectly - I can mount all partitions, connect to WiFi, and `arch-chroot` into the broken system. After doing so, I did `pacman -Syuu`, uninstalled all packages I installed today (`f2fs-tools`, `exfat-utils`, `fuse-exfat`) and updated my initramfs with `mkinitcpio -p linux`.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  Was your key-file really /home.key?

Comment: I foobared udevd by linking it to /dev/null in systemd. See my answer below. Yes, `/home.key` was the key-file. No, it's not insecure: full disk encryption and the file is only readable by root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stupidity in my `.bash_history`:

```
#1448399392
chroot rootfs /bin/bash -x <<'EOF'
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd-control.socket
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd-kernel.socket
ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system/proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
exit
EOF
```

Deleted the horrible horrible symlinks and everything's fine now. I accidentally ran the above links on the main system rather than inside the LXC container. (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_Containers#Systemd_conflicts_in_the_.2Fdev_tree)

Answer (score 1):

This `Udev cookie ... waiting for zero` also happens when any of the following conditions are true:

1. Your distribution is missing the `/lib/udev/rules.d/${NUMBER}-dm.rules` file, where `${NUMBER}` is `55` in at least Ubuntu 15.10 Wily. ([Details](http://www.spinics.net/lists/dm-crypt/msg06500.html))
2. `udev` needs to be started with `sudo service udev start`
3. `udev` is running, but needs to be restarted with `sudo service udev restart` (because you've changed the state of the system's mounted volumes in some way, and Udev needs to reset its state)

Comment: Interestingly enough I just had the exact same issue (2 years later...) trying to setup an ubuntu installation - the udev rules file isn't installed by default but the cryptsetup binary *is*. I installed a couple of the device mapper related packages and got the file (libdevmapper-dev, cryptsetup, ...)